# Adding custom field in Log Formatter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

So I have a function I have defined in a module:

```
import logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(clientname)|%(asctime)s|%(message)s',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

I want to add a client name while logging. Now mine is a flask application that spans many modules so I have defined this logger. I use getLogger to get my log in other modules. In the main flask app i.e. server.py, I have defined the logger as such:

```
info_logger = logger.setup_logger('info_logger', LOG_DIR + "status_log.csv")
```

And then I have a loop that loops over multiple clients. Whenever the loop starts I redefine the logger:

```
info_logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(info_logger, {'clientname':configData[obj]["client_name"]})
```

But this gives me errors:

1. ValueError: unsupported format character '|'
2. AttributeError: 'LoggerAdapter' object has no attribute 'manager'
3. KeyError: 'clientname'

I have been searching for a proper way to do this. I have read and followed the documentation but to no avail.